# Unity: Draw frames as fast as it can

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create video in Unity game using AVPro. I use `Update` function to save frame. `targetFrameRate` matches video frame rate, so it takes 1 minutes to generate video with 1 minute length.

Is it possible to speed up this process? I tried to use `timeScale`, but video is length is also dependent on that.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I had the same problem but I couldn't comment on you, so I spent months constantly answering what I could on this site and now I finally have comment privileges. If you find a solution you can talk to me! Thank you so much!

Comment: @狸子Neazle sorry, didn't find a solution for this

Comment: ok，still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Time.captureFramerate = framerate`

From the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-captureFramerate.html.

> If this property has a non-zero value then frame update will occur at
>   an interval of (1.0 / captureFramerate) regardless of real time and
>   the time required to render a frame.

To be able to use this method your code must support it with proper use of `Time.deltaTime` or a corresponding way.